# Call class function from constructor

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class with event listeners that I would want to add and remove as I want at certain points. The listeners should be activated when the instance is created. Since I don't want to write the same code twice I thought I would something like this:

```
export class A {
  constructor() {
    //stuff happens
    addEventListeners()
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    // Add eventlistener here
  }

  RemoveEventListeners() {
    // remove eventlistener here
  }
}
```

So later I would like to be able to do this:

```
var foo = new A();
//.....
foo.RemoveEventListeners();
```

But this doesn't work and I get a ReferenceError saying that `addEventListeners` isn't defined.

Is it possible to solve this in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.addEventListeners()` is your solution.

Remember, we're dealing with classes now, but in most languages (and still carrying over from ES5 to ES6), to refer to an object's method inside of it, you need to use the `this` keyword.

```
export class A {
  constructor() {
    //stuff happens
    this.addEventListeners() // this should work now
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    // Add eventlistener here
  }

  RemoveEventListeners() {
    // remove eventlistener here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, I'm just used to languages where the default scope in a constructor would be the class. Lazy me...

Comment: @Tistatos, JavaScript is weird. Anyway, if it helped, may I suggest marking the answer as accepted so it closes the question?

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes" ;)
Will do as soon as I can